# How do I get the default SignInManger to use Usernames instead of Emails?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making a website in ASP.net MVC 5 in Visual Studios 2015. I am trying to to get it so that when registering and logging in with an account, that it lets you use a username instead of an emails.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have changed the Model to use Usernames instead of Email addresses, I have even removed the [EmailAddress] from the models, and allowed emails to be null in the MySql database its uses. But it still won't let me use a username instead of an email when registering an account.

The error it turns says that Email can't be null or empty.

Comment: Account Controller: http://pastebin.com/UWaWnsMr
Account View Models: http://pastebin.com/Zc8xbS7h
Register View: http://pastebin.com/rTWx5qUX

Comment: problem is, that is 630 lines of combined source code. Most people narrow it down to 2 dozen or so, maybe 80 max

Comment: you have the distinct advantage of VS2015 for debugging. Others don't have such robust tools. I do, but my point is, you should use them

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that, Email is required field in ApplicationUser, As It is inherited by IdentityUser. 
so add Email field in

**RegisterViewModel**

```
 [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

On Post Action Of Register
create user using this code

```
 var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Now when you login with username then use this code

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

It will allow you to login by UserName.